# Initial conditions for the LTI systems described as a difference equations

Tags: discrete-signals, linear-systems

Why do we need the initial conditions to be zero for the LTI systems described as a difference equations?

1. First question is why do we need it for linearity? I can't think of any example of the non linear system described as a difference equation with constant coefficients.
2. The definition of TI system is that it does not depend on particular time the input is applied. I can't understand how does this definition relate to the initial conditions? Those initial conditions will be the same whenever we apply the input so why they have to be zero?

Thanx

Comment: Given different initial conditions, the output can be different (in systems with memory) even given the same identical input, but at different times after those initial conditions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that non-zero initial conditions cause a term in the output signal that *does not depend on the input signal*. This explains why a system with non-zero initial conditions can neither be linear nor time-invariant. A linear system must have a zero output for zero input. With non-zero initial conditions the output will generally be non-zero, even for a zero input signal. Alternatively, think of scaling a given input signal. A linear system will have a response that is scaled in the same way. However, the part of the output signal caused by non-zero initial conditions will not scale accordingly, because it's independent of the input signal.

The same is true concerning time-invariance. For a time-invariant system, a shifted version of the input signal must result in an output signal with the same shift. However, the output term caused by non-zero initial conditions will not shift accordingly, as it is independent of the input signal.

Consequently, a system described by a linear difference equation with constant coefficients plus initial conditions is only linear and time-invariant if the initial conditions are zero.

Comment: if the time that the initial conditions varies along with the arbitrary time-offset of the signal, might then we call the system *"time-invariant"*?  i guess that is asking for too much.  as much as asking if both the time **and** amplitudes of all the initial conditions vary with the time-delay **and** the scale of the input and calling it LTI.  but there it still doesn't pass superposition, so it's not linear.  i guess initial conditions of the LTI have to all be zero, in order to use Fourier or Laplace or Z transforms on it.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: You can use the unilateral Laplace or Z-transform with non-zero initial conditions if the system is otherwise LTI, due to the following properties: $\mathcal{L}\{f'(t)\}=sF(0)-f(0)$ and $\mathcal{Z}\{f[n+1]\}=z(F(z)-f[0])$

Comment: yeah, we know that.  it's the original way we are taught it in our EE curriculum.  i consider the unilateral $\mathcal{L}$ or $\mathcal{Z}$ (with initial conditions) to be simply a special case of the bilateral with a specific set of Dirac or Kroneckers preceding $t=0$ or $n=0$.